# How to project my iPad application in projector

Tags: ipad, projector

I need to do presentation of my application in projector, to do so I need to enable or disable any setting in my project or else want to write any extra coding to display my application in projector. The ipad youtube application is being projected, then why not my application. please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hear talk of the private MPTVOutWindow class in the MediaPlayer.framework API but it's a private API so don't plan on getting it approved by Apple like that...

Details: http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3

Comment: I tried this but its not working for my application. I have to do some other thing to get the video output.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be as impressive, but simply demo-ing or presenting in the simulator and projecting from your computer should get the job done. Does your application have some feature that makes simulator use impossible ?

While you lose some impact from "it's not a real device" it's not like the presentees could touch it anyway. Maybe use the iPad to pass around or do more one on one demos and present from the simulator.

Comment: Sry its going to be a live demo. So I cant expect my manager to use MAC machine & Simulator. All I have to do is, projecting the screen directly from the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get the MPTVOut.  It seems like the internal class has changed significantly with iOS 4, which isn't too surprising.  A work-around kind of options is rolling back the OS to 3.1.2 or 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Check this one  http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output

few others 
http://www.touchcentric.com/blog/archives/3
http://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/iphone-tv-out-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple, you can get a lighting adapter to usb cable and then usb to VGA and you can use any standard projector that will accept VGA input to project the image from your ipad. If you go this projector website [HERE](http://www.projectorsupercenter.com/projectors.html/) You will see all sorts of projectors and all of them have a VGA input that you can use. I believe there might be other adapters that you can use on the ipad as well like a lighting to HDMI or DVI.